# How do I analyze register spills with Nsight Compute?

Tags: cuda, nsight-compute

I am having trouble finding out where the data for local memory usage is. Right now, I only know to look for STL instructions in the source. I wish I could find concrete numbers.

Comment: You can get that information from NVCC with [`--resource-usage`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#generic-tool-options-resource-usage). Although I admit that the formatting isn't very easy to read, especially if you have many kernels, as their names are mangled.

Comment: I am using NVRTC though, and I can't use NVCC for what I am working on due to compiler issues. Still, shouldn't it be possible to get this info using Nsight?

Comment: I think that this information would be a good fit for the "Launch Statistics" section where one can already see register and static shared memory usage. But it seems that nobody as asked them to add the local memory usage/register spills as well.

Comment: I'll open a request then.

Comment: If you are nvrtc, you can get the local memory usage programmatically at runtime via `cuFuncGetAttribute` with the `CU_FUNC_ATTRIBUTE_LOCAL_SIZE_BYTES` attribute

Comment: Your comment reminded me, I am using CuPy, and its kernel objects have a `local_size_bytes` attribute specifying the amount of local memory used per thread.

Comment: Register spills are entirely determined at compile-time.  You can specify `-v` as a ptxas option to [NVRTC](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nvrtc/index.html#group__options) to get this info at compile time.  STL is not 100% correlated to register spills.  It is used for other purposes as well, such as to build a stack frame prior to a function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very short answer is apparently that NSight Compute currently doesn’t show local memory spills.

However:

- if you are using static compilation with nvcc, you can always see the linker spills to local memory through `-Xptxas=“-v”` i.e. turn on verbose output from the assembler.
- if you are using nvrtc and compiling at runtime, you can programmatically obtain the information via the `cuFuncGetAttribute` API with the `CU_FUNC_ATTRIBUTE_LOCAL_SIZE_BYTES` attribute if you have a handle to the function
- If you are using Cupy, kernel objects have the `local_size_bytes` attribute which is automagically populated after compilation.

[answer assembled from comments and added as a community wiki entry]